# Método TransferText

Tags: vba, csv, microsoft-access, txt, exportação

Estou tentando implementar o VBA para que assim que terminar de alimentar minha tabela, ela seja exportada para um TXT separado por ";"

O nome da minha tabela é **tabela**. 
Eu salvei minha especificação de Exportação como "EspecExport" e configurei para que os campos sejam separados por ";" e o separador decimal seja "," e o delimitador de texto seja a aspa dupla (")

E no VBA, coloquei o seguinte código:

```
Function Exportar_TXT()
        Dim nPath As String

        Let nPath = "C:\txt\"

        DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, EspecExport, "tabela", nPath & "tabela.txt", True


    End Function
```

Mas está dando o seguinte erro:

> "Erro em tempo de Execução '3441': O separador do campo da especificação do arquivo texto coincide com o separador decimal ou delimitador de texto."

**Como corrigir isso?**

Meu Access é 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Isso ocorre devido a linguagem do sistema operacional estar trabalhando com um mapa de caracteres diferente. Como a linguagem configurada é o Portugês ou outra diferente do Inglês (presumo) a vírgula é usada como um separador decimal.

Para corrigir você pode tentar:

1. Mudar a linguagem do seu sistema Operacional para Inglês.

ou

2. Dizer o tipo de codificação que você está usando na hora de exportar:

   DoCmd. TransferText acExportDelim, Chr (& H3B), "tabela", nPath & "tabela.txt", False

Sendo o "H3B" o ponto e vírgula obtido através do mapa de caracteres como visto na imagem abaixo (no meu caso U+003B):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]